# Robust comparison of positive/negative numbers value by a threshold value

Tags: javascript, coding-style

I would like to calculate whether a variable `average` differs from another variable `trackingAmount` by a certain `threshold` either positively(+) or negatively (-).

### These are the constraints:

- If the difference (+/-) between `average` and `trackingAmount` exceeds the
  `threshold` value then I would like to trigger a function
  `calcMultiTrack()`
- Threshold value in the example is called `trackTolerance`
- `average` can be positive or negative, same goes for `trackingAmount`

> What is the most robust, *(maybe **elegant** is a better word here)*, way
>   to handle such cases?

### This is what I do so far.

```
    average = average / (selItemsDimArray.length - 1); 
    var trackingAmount = 3 
    var trackTolerance = 0.2 

    //If number is positive 
    if (average >= 0) {
        if (average < (trackingAmount - trackTolerance) || average > (trackingAmount + trackTolerance)) {
            calcMultiTrack(); //This is the function I want to call if the numbers are not the same(threshold value applies)
            console.log("Positive average that differs with trackingAmount by more than +- tolerance");
        }
    }
    //Else number is negative
    else {
        if (average < (-(trackingAmount - trackTolerance)) || average > (-(trackingAmount + trackTolerance))) {
            calcMultiTrack();
            console.log("Negative average that differs with trackingAmount by more than +- tolerance");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The absolute value function is the ideal way to compute the distance between two real numbers.

```
Math.abs(average - trackingAmount) < threshold
```

Comment: I think your comparison operator is wrong. It should be >threshold, no?

Comment: Its not wrong its just different :) If all you care about is checking if it exceeds the threshold then you can use a `>`, no big deal.

Comment: No offence but what else would I care about? I just did an  `if (Math.abs(average - trackingAmount) > trackTolerance){calcMultiTrack();}` . What more is there to it if I use `>` operator?

Answer (score 2):

Normally this kind of comparison is done with

```
Math.abs(x - expected) < threshold
```

if the values have an absolute meaning and the origin is arbitrary (e.g. a position).

If otherwise the values are positive and zero based (e.g. a weight) then normally a relative distance is used

```
Math.abs(x - expected) / expected < threshold
```

where for example using `threshold = 0.1` means a `10%` error.